# How to select dropdown value in Scrollview using Appium?

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to select a dropdown value but the dropdown list comes under `android.widget.ScrollView` and i couldn't find any other locator in it.

This is how element looks like

[image]

I tried below code

```
String DESTINATION_ELEMENT_TEXT= "DE";
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+DESTINATION_ELEMENT_TEXT+"\"))");
```

It does perform the scroll till all the dropdown value but unable to select `DE` as a value and throw below Exception in the end:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be
>   located on the page using the given search parameters. For
>   documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Can someone please help me to handle scroll view and select desired value?